# How to synchronously play media on multiple computer?

Tags: windows, media-player, streaming

I have this scenario which involves a teacher and many student computers and I want the teacher to play a media file on his/her computer and then stream that video to all students simultaneously.Which means if the player seeks forward/backward the students computers also seek forward/backward.I know about the VLC but it does not support remote control,also I looked at Windows Media Player but it lacks playing to all students simultaneously. Are there any other options out there or should start coding this myself?

Comment: If you can ditch Windows, Ubuntu Linux makes this dead-easy with Pulse Audio.

Comment: I thought it was the teachers computer controlling the player, and just streaming the video data to the other computers. Why do you need remote control?

Comment: @tls it is the teacher controling the player,but I want the teachers player and the students be in synch.which means everyone sees what he/she is seeing or hearing.

Comment: I found an article describing a VLC with a remote control setup: http://www.howtogeek.com/118075/how-to-stream-videos-and-music-over-the-network-using-vlc/